# Is there a way for accessing an encrypted disk from a live environment knowing the password?

Tags: data-recovery, disk-encryption

My boss hired a guy for our ITC issues. This guy put on our laptops a security utility called McAfee Drive Encryption that encrypts the entire disk for avoiding that, in case of theft or loss someone can looks in our data. In this scenario every time I boot up my computer I have to digit a password in McAfee Drive Encryption form so that computer can start with Windows 7 Pro x64.

Now I have a great problem: probably after an update, my computer doesn’t work in the meaning that I get only blue screens before logging in. I cannot neither access in safe mode because I still get blue screens.

I absolutely need to access to my disk for copying some very important documents but, since the disk is encrypted, I cannot access it using a bootable USB or DVD with some live environment like Hiren’s BootCD.
Our technician is passed away few weeks ago and he was the only person with a good knowing of ITC in our company.

So, my question is: is there a software produced by McAfee or by others that can run from a live environment like Hiren’s BootCD or something else and can decrypt my disk using the correct password that I have?

Comment: Maybe there is a McAfee rescue disc? I would make a post on thier forum.....https://community.mcafee.com

Comment: There appears to be something called DETech by McAfee, and it does appear to offer a standalone bootable disk for drive recovery: https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB66433

Comment: Your company needs to look *very very carefully* at their working practices. This is known as the ["hit by a bus" scenario](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9128/how-can-i-prepare-for-getting-hit-by-a-bus), when only one person knows how a system works, then they are suddenly removed. The company should have been prepared for that **before** it happened.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get a hard drive to USB enclosure
2. Take old hard drive out
3. Add to enclosure
4. Plug into USB port on another device with McAfee Encryption on it.
5. Enter your password
6. copy your files off
7. Reload PC
8. Re-encrypt
9. Put files back
10. establish network backup so file are backed up to network drive so you don't have to go through this again